# Unable to keep parsing names from next pages using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script to parse different names from a table located in a ***[webpage](https://hsapps.azdhs.gov/ls/sod/SearchProv.aspx?type=DD)***. The script can scrape the names from the landing page. What I can't do is scrape the names from next pages as well.

To produce the results manually in that site, all it is required to do is press the `Start Search` button with changing nothing.

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://hsapps.azdhs.gov/ls/sod/SearchProv.aspx?type=DD'

payload = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit1': 'Start Search'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
    r = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DgFacils tr:has(> td)"):
        item_name = item.select("td")[1].text
        print(item_name)
```

> How can I keep parsing names from next pages using requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site uses a different url to handle the first page and all other pages.

I used the google chrome console to get the data format to send the request to the pagination pages.

1. Enter webpage https://hsapps.azdhs.gov/ls/sod/SearchProv.aspx?type=DD and press the `Start Search`
2. Open google chrome console.
3. Click on pagination.
4. Inspect pagination request.
   [image: Google chrome console]
5. Grab all POST parameters from console and find them in HTML of previous page.

Here is the final python code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://hsapps.azdhs.gov/ls/sod/SearchProv.aspx?type=DD'

payload = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit1': 'Start Search'
}

PAGE_COUNT = 86

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
    r = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DgFacils tr:has(> td)"):
        item_name = item.select("td")[1].text
        print(item_name)

    link = "https://hsapps.azdhs.gov/ls/sod/Provider.aspx?type=DD"

    for page in range(2, PAGE_COUNT + 1):
        payload = {
            '__VIEWSTATE': soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value'],
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value'],
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddPage',
            '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')['value'],
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField1':
                soup.select_one('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1')['value'],
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField2':
                soup.select_one('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField2')['value'],
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddPage': str(page),
        }
        r = s.post(link, data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        for item in soup.select("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DgFacils tr:has(> td)"):
            item_name = item.select("td")[1].text
            print(item_name)
```